# Best way to execute a python script in a given conda environment

Tags: python, subprocess, conda, interop, environment

I want to execute a python script `executed.py` from another python script `trigger.py` using the subprocess package. The `executed.py` must be ran in a different conda environment than `trigger.py` (let say **`executed_env`** and **`trigger_env`**). What is the best way to do that ? My current code of `trigger.py` is:

```
command = "python executed.py --option1 -dir /path/to/dir"
args = shlex.split(command)
my_subprocess = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

It returns an error since `executed.py` is ran in the **`trigger_env`** environment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did some research on any conda built-in methods and found the following. The first is a workaround, and the second the final solution built-in solution (not available at time of writing this post).

1. **conda-wrappers**.
   Guilherme Melo created a wrappers for the python executables within a conda environment. If you set it as the python interpreter in your IDE, e.g. PyCharm, it will activate the conda environment from which it is called, and then call the python interpreter. 
   Look here under section "Creating conda wrappers":
   https://pypi.org/project/exec-wrappers/
2. **conda run**.
   A long discussion on the conda github page on [a standard and fast way to execute a command inside an environment](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2379) led to the implementation of a new command (actually a re-invocation as it was available before):
   `conda run`

It is described in [issue #7320](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/7320) and will be released in [conda-4.6](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) hopefully in October 2018!

Comment: Just to add, because I keep messing up the syntax:
`conda run -n envname python -c "print('Hello!')"`

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to use the other python then I believe you simply need to use the full path to the other python in your `command`.

Try going into your `executed_env` (i.e. `source activate executed_env` if Linux) and do `which python`. Let's assume that returns `HOME/.conda/envs/executed_env/bin/python` now that becomes the python that you use in your command -- i.e. `command = "HOME/.conda/envs/executed_env/bin/python executed.py --option1 -dir /path/to/dir"`. This

For example, let's run `executed.py` in a different python version.

- Create your py27 environment `conda create -n py27 python=2.7` this is the `trigger_env`.
- Create your py35 environment `conda create -n py35 python=3.5` this is the `executed_env`.
- Get the full python path to py35 by running `source activate py35` and then `which python` (let's call that EXECUTED_PYTHON for this description). Deactivate via `source deactivate`.
- Then we create `executed.py`

  ```
  import sys
  print(sys.version)
  ```
- Then the `trigger.py` (included the arguments but they are doing nothing)

  ```
  command = "EXECUTED_PYTHON executed.py --option1 -dir /path/to/dir"
  args = shlex.split(command)
  my_subprocess = subprocess.Popen(args)
  ```
- Now let's run it in the `trigger_env` -- `source activate py27` and `python trigger.py`.
- This prints `3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc. [...]` (3.5 being the important part). You can see it is using the other python in the `executed_env`.

Comment: I thought about this when I wrote my question. For deployment it's not really comfortable...

Answer (score 3):

Using conda on windows environment, I just copied the way conda does for starting different jupyter notebooks each from a different environment. All shortcuts call to "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\cwp.py" script using "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe", then with additional parameters you can choose the environment and the file to be executed.

In my case, environment name = AutomateXXReporting, file to be executed = C:\Users\ismael.serrano\Documents\GIT\xxx\notebooks\exports\get_JIRA_user_streams.py

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\ismael.serrano\.conda\envs\AutomateXXReporting C:\Users\ismael.serrano\.conda\envs\AutomateXXReporting\python.exe C:\Users\ismael.serrano\Documents\GIT\xxx\notebooks\exports\get_JIRA_user_streams.py
```

Previously I had proceed successfully as Paul indicated, but reached a case where it was not sufficient. The python from the full path was not able to find some libraries, using cwp.py it worked.