# Activate conda environment using subprocess

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I am trying to find version of pandas:

```
def check_library_version():
    print("Checking library version")
    subprocess.run(f'bash -c "conda activate {ENV_NAME};"', shell=True)
    import pandas
    pandas.__version__
```

Desired output:
1.1.3

Output:

> Checking library version
>
> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
> use 'conda activate'. To initialize your shell, run
>
> ```
> $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
> ```
>
> Currently supported shells are:
>
> - bash
> - fish
> - tcsh
> - xonsh
> - zsh
> - powershell
>
> See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
>
> IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running
> 'conda init'.

To clarify, I don't seek to update the environment of the currently running script; I just want to briefly activate that environment and find out which Pandas version is installed there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using subprocess in anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819719/using-subprocess-in-anaconda-environment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense at all; the Conda environment you activated is terminated when the subprocess terminates.

You should (`conda init` and) `conda activate` your virtual environment *before* you run any Python code.

If you just want to activate, run a simple Python script as a subprocess of your current Python, and then proceed with the current script outside of the virtual environment, try something like

```py
subprocess.run(f"""conda init bash
    conda activate {ENV_NAME}
    python -c 'import pandas; print(pandas.__version__)'""",
    shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', check=True)
```

This just prints the output to the user; if your Python program wants to receive it, you need to add the correct flags;

```py
check = subprocess.run(...whatever..., text=True, capture_output=True)
pandas_version = check.stdout
```

(It is unfortunate that there is no `conda init sh`; I don't think anything in the above depends on `executable='/bin/bash'` otherwise. Perhaps there is a way to run this in POSIX `sh` and drop the Bash requirement.)