# How to activate a Conda environment within a Python script?

Tags: python, conda, environment

I have a script using `os.system(cmd)` to run a pipe. I need the pipe to run in a specific Conda environment, so I tried to do something like this:

```
cmd = 'conda activate base && ' + cmd
os.system(cmd)
```

However, I get:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

The fact is, my shell is properly configured. If I run the same `cmd` in the shell, everything works as expected.

I have tried using `subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)` as well, but I get the same result.

Is there a way to run `conda activate base` from within a python script?

Comment: If this is macOS/linux, you need to `source <conda-base>/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` before you can run conda commands.

Comment: @cel It worked. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: my anaconda installation is perfectly valid yet conda.sh in that particular path is not set with executable permissions. Hence use `. <conda-base>/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` to force its execution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using subprocess in anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819719/using-subprocess-in-anaconda-environment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conda activate` is really intended to be used in interactive settings (shells/command prompts).  But you can use `conda run` to execute a particular python script within a given environment.

Try this instead:

```
conda run -n <environment> <script_name>
```

Comment: I get `permission denied`

Comment: I can't reproduce that error, however it sounds as if you already have a solution as posted by @cel