# How to execute multiple commands in an anaconda prompt with python?

Tags: python, automation, anaconda, environment

I have different conda enviroments for different programs that need to be running at the same time (as part of a complex system). So everytime I'm working on this project I have to manually open about six anaconda terminals and copy/paste the commands in each terminal.

I'm looking for a solution where I can write code to open the terminal and execute the instructions. This way I can run this single code to have all of them running.

I saw some people using python to run shell commands but not for Anaconda Prompt.

If you have any idea of what I can use for that, it would be great.

Comment: You might be able to run those commands from a single shell with a script, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771560/how-to-activate-a-conda-environment-within-a-python-script), particularly the line in the accepted answer `conda run -n <environment> <script_name>`. Should run on shells that have been initialized for conda (note: I haven't tried this myself, just pointing to the other question as a potential solution).